# Two trigonometry-based turtle codes not giving similar output

Tags: python-3.x, trigonometry, turtle-graphics

This is my first time posting a question.
I'm having trouble creating a code involving cosine, and I am not recieving the desired outcome. What is even more confusing is the fact that the two codes should be creating similar images (Explained later). Any ideas?

In the code below, these variables represent:
Y is a counter, making sure that the code only runs until the specified amount of radi is produced.
W is the colour randomly generated.
Z is the angle turn from 0 degrees. (The turtle's angle resets due to turtle.home).
Adjacent is the smallest length from centre to a line.
Radi is the amount of lines protruding from the centre.

```
def Triangle(Radi, Adjacent):
y = 0
if (Radi) % 1 == 0:
    while (Radi) > y:
        y = y + 1
        w = randhex()
        z = 360/(Radi)*y
        turtle.left(z+30)
        turtle.color(w)
        if z > 300:
            turtle.forward(Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*(60 - (z - 300))/180))
        elif z > 240:
            turtle.forward(Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*(z - 240)/180))
        elif z > 180:
            turtle.forward(Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*(60 - (z - 180))/180))
        elif z > 120:
            turtle.forward(Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*(z - 120)/180))
        elif z > 60:
            turtle.forward(Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*(60 - (z - 60))/180))
        else:
            turtle.forward(Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*z/180))
        turtle.home()
```

Above is my first code which appears to work, giving these results when `Triangle(100,180)` is entered (Please note that `randhex()` is a custom function that generates random colours).

[Triangle(100,180) results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1B13.png)

My apologies if my variable naming creativity is annoying.
In this code, counter represents 'y' and angle represents 'z' from the previous code
Here is my second code:

```
def Polygon(Radi, Adjacent, Sides):
    counter = 0
    if Sides % 1 != 0 or Sides == 2 or Sides <= 0:
        print ("INVALID")
    elif Sides == 1:
        while Radi > counter:
            counter = counter + 1
            colour = randhex()
            turn = 360/Radi*counter
            turtle.left(turn)
            turtle.color(colour)
            turtle.forward(Adjacent)
            turtle.home()
    else:
        while Radi > counter:
            counter = counter + 1
            colour = randhex()
            turn = 360/Radi*counter
            turtle.left(turn)
            turtle.color(colour)
            segment = str(counter/Radi*Sides*2)
            position = segment.index('.')
            test = int(segment[:position])
            if test % 2 == 1:
                length = Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*(turn - (360 - 360/Sides*((test+1)/2)))/180)
                turtle.forward(length)
            else:
                length = Adjacent/math.cos(math.pi*(180/Sides - (turn - (360 - 180/Sides*(test+1))))/180)
                turtle.forward(length)
            turtle.home()
```

Above is my second code, being the one I'm struggling with. Once again, apologies for my variable names being annoying and some of the maths not simplified. I find it easier to see how my ideas make sense when I leave them as they are. Below are my results for my second code after entering `Polygon(180,100,3)`.

[Polygon(180,100,3) results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lyNa.png)

As you can see, it didn't go quite how I was planning.
I should also note that I tried substituting the numbers into the codes where one of the codes were giving a different line length. Sometimes they even went in an opposite direction (because the number came out negative). I did this on the Google calculator, but it seemed that both codes would give the same answer, but they corresponded to what the second code was outputing, not the first.

If you want me to explain anything leave a comment.
But if it turns out that my code is wrong (Which I believe), could you please point me to what I need to do instead.
I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is too complicated to debug.  The unhelpful variable names, the  lack of comments and excessively long equations make it hard to read.

If we consider the equation suggested in this answer to [Is there an equation to describe regular polygons?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/726544) then your original triangle code simplifies to:

```
import math
import turtle

def randhex():
    """ substitute random color generator here """
    return 'red'

def triangle(radii, adjacent):

    if radii % 1 != 0:  # only whole numbers (int or float) allowed
        return

    counter = 1

    while counter <= radii:

        angle = counter * (2 * math.pi / radii)
        turtle.setheading(angle)

        colour = randhex()
        turtle.color(colour)

        radius = adjacent / math.cos(angle % (math.pi / 1.5) - math.pi / 3)

        turtle.forward(radius)
        turtle.backward(radius)

        counter += 1

turtle.radians()  # avoid individual conversions, switch to radians

triangle(100, 180)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

And the general polygon solution can be achieved with just a few changes:

```
import math
import turtle

def randhex():
    """ substitute random color generator here """
    return 'red'

def polygon(radii, adjacent, sides):

    if radii % 1 != 0:  # only whole numbers (int or float) allowed
        return

    if sides % 1 != 0 or sides == 2 or sides <= 0:
        return

    counter = 1

    while counter <= radii:

        angle = counter * (2 * math.pi / radii)
        turtle.setheading(angle)

        colour = randhex()
        turtle.color(colour)

        if sides == 1:  # special case, a circle
            radius = adjacent
        else:
            radius = adjacent / math.cos(angle % (math.pi / (sides / 2)) - math.pi / sides)

        turtle.forward(radius)
        turtle.backward(radius)

        counter += 1

turtle.radians()  # avoid individual conversions, switch to radians

polygon(100, 180, 3)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

With `polygon(100, 90, 5)` looking like:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts to decypher my code. I have never used 'for i in range' and ' if not isinstance before. But I'm still wondering why my triangle code managed to work even though  it displayed incorrect lengths when I punched it into a calculator.

Comment: @AlexanderJephtha, the `for` loop can better express some `while` loop situations but I've backed off to `while` loops, and your original whole number check, so you can more easily compare your solution with mine.

Comment: Thank you for the change. Much more clear now, as the while loop is the only loop i ever bothered to learn because it seems to work with all my codes. But other than that I'll keep in mind about turtle.radians, try to clean my future codes and write descriptions for what's happening. Great learning experience for future turtle or even python codes! However, I'm still wondering what made the first code work and the second not work, even though when I did the calculations they both shouldn't work. I won't mark this question complete until someone can explain why this is so.

Comment: I have just tried out the code. I know it has been over a month but i haven't done much with python for a while.